# TypeScript override existing values and enforce field value

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to figure out how to extend an interface's optional values such that if one field is set to a specific value then another field *must* exist, I cannot figure this out – how is this done?

The goal is this:

- If `restricted` is `true` then `apiData` is still optional.
- If `apiData` is set then `restricted` *must* be set to `true`.

```js
interface IRoute {
  path?: string
  restricted?: boolean
  exact?: boolean
  component: string
  layout?: string
  apiData?: string
}

interface IRouteWithData extends Omit<IRouteConfigItem, 'restricted apiData'> {
  restricted: true
  apiData: FC
}

type TRoute = IRouteWithData | IRouteConfigItem

const routeConfig: TRoute[] = [
  {
    path: '/foo',
    restricted: false, // this should be an error
    exact: true,
    component: 'something',
    apiData: 'some data'
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    restricted: true, // this is fine
    exact: true,
    component: 'something'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So solutions is a sum type, you were close by using union, but we need to define discriminants in order to allow TS to infer the difference.

```
// all fields which are static in all sum elements
interface IRouteBase {
  path?: string
  exact?: boolean
  component: string
  layout?: string
}

// type representing that if restricted is true - apiData needs to be set
interface IRouteWithData extends IRouteBase  {
  restricted: true
  apiData: string
}
// type representing that if restricted is false- apiData is optional
interface IRouteMaybeData extends IRouteBase  {
  restricted: false
  apiData?: string
}

type TRoute = IRouteWithData | IRouteMaybeData;

// example use
const mustHaveApiData: TRoute = {
  component: 'component',
  restricted: true, // error you need to set apiData
}

const notNeedHaveApiData: TRoute = {
  component: 'component',
  restricted: false, // no error, apiData is optional
}
```

More information about using sum types is included in my article - https://dev.to/macsikora/more-accurate-the-type-better-the-code-202l. Enjoy!